# Выбрать список значений атрибута объектов из списка объектов

Tags: python

```
class Unit:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    range = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y, range):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.range = range

test1 = Unit(10, 10, 5)
test2 = Unit(20, 20, 5)
test3 = Unit(30, 30, 7)

test_list = [test1, test2, test3]
```

Есть такое описание класса Unit. Также созданы три объекта данного класса. Как получить из этого списка объектов список атрибута объектов, допустим атрибута 'y'? Т.е. конечный список должен содержать только значения атрибута всех объектов.

```
test_list_attr = [test1.y, test2.y, test3.y]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_list_attr = [i.y for i in test_list]
```

или

```
from operator import attrgetter

test_list_attr = list(map(attrgetter('y'), test_list))
```